# How to setinterval with php in current page

Tags: php, jquery, innerhtml

Hi The following script is not working for me

```
$(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                var placeHTML="<?php echo $domains_all; ?>";
                $("#domains").html(placeHTML);  
            }, 2000);
        });
```

I know that we can load the php from external php file using the following script

```
$('#myParagraph').load('myPage.php');
```

But, I dont want to load from external file. Because, in top of the page I am using php GET method

so, it is not better to load external php file. I want to add innerHTML with setinterval.

How should I want to modify the script?

Comment: def to less information. what is $domains_all? Is it set? all sounds like an array. Is it? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: $domains_all .= "<tr><td>".$domain."</td></tr>"; // this is domains_all

Comment: Two questions: What does "Not working" mean?  What does your JavaScript look like in "view source?"

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention this following html  <!----html area starts here -->  <tbody id="domains"></tbody> <!---html area end here -->. Between the above tbody tag no any outputs diplay. But In page source, between the script tag the domain name displays like this --- var placeHTML="testdomain.com"; ---

Comment: I think you are mixing what javascript and what php is???

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ujj8dpqd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, it's too less information for a real answer, but you can't echo a php variable inside a php variable in jQuery/javascript.

You can give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            var placeHTML="<?php echo $domain; ?>";
            $("#domains").html('<tr><td>'+placeHTML+'</td></tr>');
        }, 2000);
    });
```

or this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        setInterval(function() {

            var placeHTML ="testdomain.com";
            $("#domains").append('<tr><td>'+placeHTML+'</td></tr>');
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried                           $("#domains").html('<tr><td>'+placeHTML+'</td></tr>'); but, now the out put displaying as <tbody id="domains"><tr><td></td></tr></tbody>. Testdomain is not displaying.

Comment: Yes, as I said, the variable is not set. You are mixing javascript with php

Comment: Yes I agree that. We could not echo php variable in jquery/Ajax